# Sveltestrap navbar items and links disappear with static adapter

Tags: bootstrap-5, svelte, sveltekit, sveltestrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs14B.png)

When i turn adapter to static in svelte.config.js the navbar items and links disappear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRnLu.png)

#### svelte.config.js

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess} from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
// import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/\*\* @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} \*/
const config = {
// Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
// for more information about preprocessors
preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown. On some platforms
            // these options are set automatically — see below
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false,
            strict: true
          })
    
    },

};

export default config;
```

#### +layout.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
  import {
    Collapse,
    Navbar,
    NavbarToggler,
    NavbarBrand,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    NavLink,
    Image
  } from 'sveltestrap';

  let isOpen = false;

  function handleUpdate(event) {
    isOpen = event.detail.isOpen;
  }
</script>

<Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
<NavbarBrand href="/">sveltestrap</NavbarBrand>
<NavbarToggler on:click={() => (isOpen = !isOpen)} />
<Collapse {isOpen} navbar expand="md" on:update={handleUpdate}>
  <Nav class="ms-auto" navbar>
    <NavItem>
      <NavLink href="#components/">Components</NavLink>
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem>
      <NavLink href="https://github.com/bestguy/sveltestrap">GitHub</NavLink>
    </NavItem>
  </Nav>
</Collapse>
</Navbar>

<idv>
  <slot></slot>
</idv>
```

#### +layout.js

```
// This can be false if you're using a fallback (i.e. SPA mode)
// export const prerender = true;
// export const trailingSlash = 'always';
export const ssr = false;
```

I take a looke to sorce code of rendered page in browser and there is no <collapse></collapse> block inside DOM.